# Редактирование БД через модальное окно

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

Помогите реализовать функцию редактирования данных через модальное окно в данной таблице. Подскажите каким способом необходимо передавать id для редактирования БД из модального окна в код со скриптом на UPDATE

```html
     <script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js'></script>
 <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <table class="table table-list-search">
        <div class="col col-xs-6">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Студенты</h3>
                  </div>
   <div class="col col-xs-6 text-right">

                  </div>
     <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Имя</th>
                            <th>Фамилия</th>
                            <th>Отчество</th>
       <th class="text-right">Действие</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
       <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
                        <tr>

                            <td><?php echo $row1[1];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row1[2];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
       
<!--- Редактировать ---> <td class="text-right"> <form method="post" action="delete.php">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product_view"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>      
<!--- Удалить --->   <form method="post" action="delete.php">
       <button type= "submit" class='btn btn-danger' name="delete"   value="<?=$row1['0']; ?>" >   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></span></form> </td>
      </tr>
                        <?php endwhile;?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                

                
<!-- Меню редактирования -->
<div class="modal fade product_view" id="product_view">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="class pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Редактирование данных о студентах</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12 product_content">
       <form action= "#" method= "POST"> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <h2 class="heading">Ф.И.О.</h2>
      <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" id="name" class="floatLabel" name="name">
       <label for="name">Имя</label>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" id="famil" class="floatLabel" name="famil">
       <label for="famil">Фамилия</label>
      </div>
       <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" id="otchest" class="floatLabel" name="otchest">
       <label for="otchest">Отчество</label>
      
      <div class="space-ten"></div>        
                        <div class="btn-ground"></div>  
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="edit"   value="<?=$row['0']; ?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Подтвердить</button> 
                        </div>                       
      </div>
      </form>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php'; 

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
        or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
     $link->set_charset("utf8");

if (isset($_POST['edit'])){

    $id = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']));
    $name = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']));
    $famil = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['famil']));
    $otchest = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['otchest']));
    $edit=$_POST['edit']; 

    $query ="UPDATE vse SET name='$name', famil='$famil', otchest='$otchest' WHERE id='$edit'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

        if($result)
    {
        header('Location: '.'studenti.php');
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Вешайте на кнопку событие "click" и отправляйте данные на сервер при помощи ajax
Вот как-то так:

```
$('button).on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var user = $('form').serialize();
   $.ajax({
     url: 'path/to/script',
     type: 'POST',
     data: user,
     success: function(data){
        alert('Success')
     }
   })
})
```